# i need help to make a where or a find_by to push the object name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to programming and created a join table that pulls people to the table and the table books. in the table show only shows the id of the book. must show the name of the book that belongs to this id. tried to make a where and find_by however not got success. Follow my show.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Pessoa:</strong>
  ***<%= @leitura.pessoa_id %>***
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Livro:</strong>
  ***<%= @leitura.livro_id %>***
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_leitura_path(@leitura) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', leituras_path %>
```

Comment: Hi Breno! Welcome to SO. Hopefully you find somebody who can answer your question, though you'd probably have more luck if your code was in English, or you provided translations! (eg, what is `pessoa`?)

Comment: You should also include the content of `models/leitura.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
Livro.find(@leitura.livro_id).name
```

(`find_by(id: ...)` would also work. The difference is that it would return nil instead of raising a exception no record exists for the given ID.)

But if your associations are correctly set up, this simpler code should also work:

```
@leitura.livro.name
```

(You can use something like `@leiture.livro.try(:name) || '(no value)'` to avoid errors if `livro` may be absent.)

This requires that you have a `belongs_to` call in your `Leitura` class.